# How do I scrape?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.jab.de/tr/en/productadvancedsearch?searchTerm=&page=1"
website = requests.get(url)
html = website.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

urunListesi = soup.find("section",{"class":"results"}).find("div",{"class":"col-item details"})
# print(urunListesi)

for urun in urunListesi:
    link = urun.div.a.get("href")
    print(link)
    print("----------------------------\n")
```

when I operate to that code it returns None, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of me scraping the price of bitcoin!
I will explain how everything works after this.
TRY IT!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cmc = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+price+of+bitcoin")
soup = BeautifulSoup(cmc.content, "html.parser")
# with open("soup.txt", "w") as f:
#     f.write(soup.prettify())
class_of_text = "BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd"
price = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':class_of_text}).find("div", attrs={'class':class_of_text}).text

print("Here is the price of bitcoin:")
print(price)
```

The explaining part.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cmc = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=what+you+want+to+scrape+with+pluses+instead+of+spaces")
soup = BeautifulSoup(cmc.content, "html.parser")

with open("soup.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

This writes a file called soup.txt. In there will be the html of the file. Look into that file and find what text you want to scrape. Command/control f will help you find it. Then, copy the class. It should look something like this: `BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd`. Make that a variable. Then make a new variable equal to `soup.find("div", attrs={'class':Your_First_Variable}).find("div", attrs={'class':Your_First_Variable}).text`. The second variable will have the scraped text.

After you have found the class in soup.txt, you can delete,

```
with open("soup.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

Comment if you need further clarification or help.